# Streaming binary file from SQL Database through Apache Camel back to endpoint

Tags: java, rest, servlets, streaming, apache-camel

I'm trying to get some `varbinary` data out of an SQL database, when a REST call is made to my Camel service. I can get the data as a byte array and set that as the body of the Camel `Exchange`, and then `Servlet` will return that as raw bytes to the caller (a web browser, application, whatever).

I'm now at the point where I want to do this with a stream rather than holding all the bytes in memory. If I use `JdbcTemplate`, the connection and streams I can get from my resultset are all closed when the `.query` method is complete, even if I try to return an `InputStream` and set this as the `Exchange` body. This prevents me from streaming data from the DB, straight through Camel, and back to the caller.

If I were to write the jdbc stuff myself, I'd be able to set the stream as the exchange body while it was open, but then I don't think I have a chance to close the connection and stream that I opened to do so, and would eventually run out of resources due to that.

I had a look at onCompletion, but I don't know how I could use that to close streams and connections that I have no reference to, and I'm not sure if that will definitely execute after all data has been streamed back to the caller.

I'm using the REST DSL in Camel 2.14.1, and the Servlet component. Is there any way to accomplish this without writing out to a file which I clean up later on with a timed task somewhere? I'd like to avoid that, as otherwise you have a race condition to stream the data back before a dumb timer cleans it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this turned out to be, in your bean where you query your DB, get a `Connection` from a `ConnectionPool`, create your `PreparedStatement` to get whatever column is your data, and execute it to request your binary data using `ResultSet.getBinaryStream`.

That gives you an `InputStream` which you can set as your Camel `Exchange` body, and if you're using the REST DSL you must set `RestBindingMode.off` on your REST endpoint.

After setting it as your exchange body, attach the stream, connection and result set as properties on your exchange using `setProperty("your_name_here", closeableresource)`.

*Note that setting these as headers may cause `Servlet` to bind them into the response, and besides there's usually a max header size which these will not fit into.*

Error handling in your bean should deal with cleaning up connections, etc, in the error case.

Then on the route that your REST endpoint calls, have an `onCompletion` clause, which will only execute when the consumer of the REST call is done. In that clause, call a `Processor` which extracts the properties you previously set for the resources you need to close, null check them, and close them.

Apologies for the lack of code snippet, hopefully I'll have time to come back to this, but the above should be enough.

tl;dr: `onCompletion` **will** execute after all of the stream has been passed back over the connection, at least for `Servlet` with Apache Camel.